# CoreUi Laravel Admin Template Failed to build using node-gyp@3.8.0

Tags: laravel, core-ui, npm-build

I am installing laravel CoreUi Admin template when  I ran npm install it gives me build error.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\laragon_new\www\sms\coreui\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.4.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\B L Praveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\laragon_new\\www\\sms\\coreui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\laragon_new\www\sms\coreui\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed
```

I have installed python39 on my system.

I tried from command line I get the same error.

Please let me know right syntax to get the sys.version_info

I have python3 installed

but  npm installed node-gyp@3.8.0 which uses legacy python statements

How to run with using node-gyp@latest?

The issue with node-sass using node-gy@3.8.0

[image]

Comment: super personal recommendation, you are using windows 10, install WSL and your problems will be solved, never use CMD again, use WSL, google it, it is really simple to install.

Comment: I get same error.Is the Pyhton syntax correct?"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: I am looking on google and I cannot find `print "xxx"`, but `print("xxx")`, so I think that is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `npm shrinkwrap`

it created `npm-shrinkwrap.json`

I edited the node-gyp version to 8.0.1

I got the node-gyp latest version from command line `node view node-gyp version`

Then finally ran `npm install`